# Codeigniter: fetch and sum field values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Please help with this...

I want to write a ***query to display sum of all marks of each student*** ( OR each record of a table - 1st CA + 2ND CA + EXAM SCORE = TOTAL).

I can display the marks successfully but can't fill in the 'Total'.

**Please view the picture below.**

[View table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rVlD.png)

**Please find my "mark table" and "subject table" structure below...**

[View table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyqVO.jpg)

Using the MVC architecture...

**Here is my Model**

```
function get_obtained_first_ca( $exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id , $student_id) {
    $marks = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                'subject_id' => $subject_id,
                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                            'student_id' => $student_id))->result_array();

    foreach ($marks as $row) {
        echo $row['first_ca'];
    }}

         function get_obtained_second_ca( $exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id , $student_id) {
    $marks2 = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                'subject_id' => $subject_id,
                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                            'student_id' => $student_id))->result_array();

    foreach ($marks2 as $row) {
        echo $row['second_ca'];
    }}

    function get_obtained_exam_score( $exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id , $student_id) {
    $marks3 = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                'subject_id' => $subject_id,
                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                            'student_id' => $student_id))->result_array();

    foreach ($marks3 as $row) {
        echo $row['exam_score'];
    }
}
```

Here is my autoload.php file content

```
$autoload['model'] = array('crud_model'); // The crud_model is my main model file.
```

**Here is my controller**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('session');
```

**Here is my view**

```
      <table>
        <tbody>
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Subject</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">1st CA</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">2nd CA</td>
         ...
        <td style="text-align: center;">Total</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <?php 
        $total_marks = 0;
        $total_grade_point = 0;
        $subjects = $this->db->get_where('subject' , array(
                'class_id' => $class_id , 'year' => $running_year
        ))->result_array();
        foreach ($subjects as $row3):
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $row3['name'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <?php
                    $obtained_mark_query = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                                'subject_id' => $row3['subject_id'],
                                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                                            'student_id' => $student_id , 
                                                                'year' => $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description
                                            ));
                    if($obtained_mark_query->num_rows() > 0){
                        $marks = $obtained_mark_query->result_array();
                        foreach ($marks as $row4) {
                            echo $row4['first_ca'];
                            $total_marks += $row4['first_ca'];
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php
                    $obtained_mark_query = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                                'subject_id' => $row3['subject_id'],
                                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                                            'student_id' => $student_id , 
                                                                'year' => $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description
                                            ));
                    if($obtained_mark_query->num_rows() > 0){
                        $marks = $obtained_mark_query->result_array();
                        foreach ($marks as $row4) {
                            echo $row4['second_ca'];
                            $total_marks += $row4['second_ca'];
                        }
                    }
                ?></td>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
            <?php
                echo $total_mark; // Here is where I need to fetch my Total

                ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Your effort to help me fill the total column is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!